# Dynamically insert new row using javascript, but how to save these multiple row in php/mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have create multiple row by using javascript. Now how to save these row in mysql. I already using some type of code, its not working. here my code is 
    `[http://jsfiddle.net/bb2pJ/]` 
and php code for adding these value.

`

```
include "config.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

 foreach ($_POST['code1'] as $key => $value) 
    {
        $code1 = $_POST["code1"][$key];
        $product1 = $_POST["product_name1"][$key];
        $qty = $_POST["quantity1"][$key];
        $rate = $_POST["amount_name1"][$key];
        $total = $_POST["total_name1"][$key];


        $sql = mysql_query("insert into      testing(code,product,qty,rate,total)values('$code1','$product1','$qty1','$rate1','$total1')")or die(mysql_error());        
    }

}   
?>`
```

Comment: simply create json of your table data and save that json with php

Comment: thanks for your reply. how to create json. is there any example.

Comment: [Look This question to create json from mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281963/how-to-build-a-json-array-from-mysql-database)

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507368/convert-html-table-rows-into-php-array-and-save-it-to-database

Comment: no i can't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

From you Js fiddle code, you are trying to post array of values for each field (ie code, proddname, ...).

How are submitting these values? If not passing through ajax post, then you need to declare fields names like code[], product_name[] ... as array for all fields so they will be submitted as array.

Rest code you have writtten above should work by using proper field name like code for code[] ... .

Please put proper spacing between your keywords and values/fieldname in your insert into.. statement.